# Enable Retention option is missing in SharePoint 2013 List - Information Management Policy Settings (Content type - Item)

Tags: 2013, list, content-type, retention, information-management

**Enable Retention** Option is missing in SharePoint 2013 List Information Management Policy Settings (Content type - Item),

[image]

In my dev site the option is there (dev site is restored from a site collection back up from prod) and same site and site collection features are enabled

[image]

Please kindly advise what I should do to get that option?

Answer (score 0):

Retention has to be enabled through Central Administration

Central Administration > Security > Configure Information Management Policy (Under Information Policy) > Retention > Change the Status to  "Available for use in new site and list policies."